# How to set value of a variable by matching values from a XPathNodeIterator and another XML in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We need to set value of a variable MaterialGroup by matching value from a XPathNodeIterator (XSLT version of String Array) and an XML tree.

XPathNodeIterator has following data.

```
<root>
   <item>item1</item>
   <item>item2</item>
   <item>item3</item>
   <item>item4</item>
</root>
```

XML has following data.

```
<MyRoot>
<XrefDescriptionTable>
        <value>
            <ItemDescription>item0</ItemDescription>
            <Group>GroupA</Group>
         </value>
         <value>
            <ItemDescription>item3</ItemDescription>
            <Group>GroupB</Group>
         </value>
         <value>
            <ItemDescription>item5</ItemDescription>
            <Group>GroupC</Group>
         </value>
    </XrefDescriptionTable>
</MyRoot>
```

We will iterate over Item list and will try to find a matching ItemDescription in other XML. When item and ItemDescription will have same value, corrosponding Group will be our result.

in given example, MaterialGroup will have output "GroupB".

Note :-  there will either be **only one or zero** matching case.

i have tried following XSLT code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:n="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
    xmlns:cs="urn:cs"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl ffs n m d cs"
    

<xsl:variable name="MaterialGroup" >
    <xsl:for-each select="cs:getItemList('item1,item2,item3,item4')"> 
            <xsl:if test="/MyRoot/XrefDescriptionTable/value/ItemDescription=current()">
                 <xsl:value-of select="/MyRoot/XrefDescriptionTable/value[ItemDescription=current()]/Group"/>
            </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<msxsl:script implements-prefix="my" language="C#">
    public XPathNodeIterator getItemList(string itemList)
    {
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("root"));
       using (XmlWriter writer = doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
       {
         foreach (string item in itemList.split(','))
         {
           writer.WriteElementString("item", item);
         }
       }
       return doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().Select("item");
     }
  </msxsl:script>
```

I am getting Empty string "" instead of "GroupB" as output.

Comment: You need to explain what your technology stack is. The fact that you're using `msxsl:script` suggests it's something in the Microsoft world, but that still leaves lots of options.

Comment: @MichaelKay thanks for suggestion. i have added all used namespace-uri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to try e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="items" select="cs:getItemList('item1,item2,item3,item4')"/>
```

and then select e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="MaterialGroup" select="/MyRoot/XrefDescriptionTable/value[ItemDescription=$items]/Group"/>
```

That way, if the input XML is e.g.

```
<MyRoot>
  <XrefDescriptionTable>
    <value>
      <ItemDescription>item1</ItemDescription>
      <Group>GroupA</Group>
    </value>
    <value>
      <ItemDescription>item3</ItemDescription>
      <Group>GroupB</Group>
    </value>
    <value>
      <ItemDescription>item5</ItemDescription>
      <Group>GroupC</Group>
    </value>
  </XrefDescriptionTable>
</MyRoot>
```

the result of the XSLT below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/mf"
>

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="my" language="C#">
    public XPathNodeIterator getItemList(string itemList)
    {
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("root"));
    using (XmlWriter writer = doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild())
    {
    foreach (string item in itemList.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None))
    {
    writer.WriteElementString("item", item);
    }
    }
    return doc.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().Select("item");
    }
  </msxsl:script>
  
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="items" select="my:getItemList('item1,item2,item3,item4')"/>

  <xsl:variable name="MaterialGroup" select="/MyRoot/XrefDescriptionTable/value[ItemDescription=$items]/Group"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Results>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$MaterialGroup"/>
    </Results>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

run with XslCompiledTransform and EnableScript XsltSettings enabled, is:

```
<Results>
  <Group>GroupA</Group>
  <Group>GroupB</Group>
</Results>
```

Comment: this answer worked partially. it is using only first element of Items for comparison. Could you please improve it ?

Comment: @SumantKumarMandal, the variable `MaterialGroup` contains the matched `Group` elements of all `item`s, see the above edit (I haven't changed any of the previously suggested code, just added a full sample to output the variable contents).

Comment: It worked for me. There was a mistake from my side. Thanks :)